# Vulkan: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vulkan

I've been running Overwatch using Lutris on my [MSI Laptop](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GV62-7RE/Specification) (see link for specs). However, recently I've been encountering problems. When I try to run Overwatch, a get this error message:

```
No compatible graphics hardware
0xE0070160
```

It used to all work fine. I ran the command `vulkaninfo` and the following error message showed up:

```
/build/vulkan-tools-_xrZWD/vulkan-tools-1.1.101.0+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:630: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

So there seems to be something wrong with vulkan, which I suspect might be the cause of the Overwatch problem.

However, this all used to work fine. The only thing I can think of that might have caused issues is me installing i3wm, but I'm really not sure.

I've reinstalled vulkan several times, as well as Lutris and my Nvidia drivers. No luck.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3. I installed Overwatch by following [this](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-play-overwatch-with-lutris-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial. According to [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver) my graphics card should support vulkan.

Any ideas?

(Might want to add that I'm really new to linux.)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the following from terminal:

1. Install mesa-vulkan-drivers and vulkan-tools

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade`
   sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-tools`
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` using

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   and append

   ```
   amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0
   ```

   to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

   Example: Change

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0"
   ```

   Save the edit
3. Update GRUB and restart the system.

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   shutdown -r now
   ```

Comment: This worked for me thanks!  Minus appending "amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0" to /etc/default/grub.  That threw an error for me,

Comment: Correction!  It worked at first, then stopped working (don't ask me why).  I played around with the options and this ended up working.   
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=1"`

I changed radeon.si_support to 1.